# How to divide a spark dataframe into n different chunks and convert them to dataframe and append into one?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe of 100000 rows. Is there a way to loop though 1000 rows and convert them to pandas dataframe using toPandas() and append them into a new dataframe?

Directly changing this by using toPandas() is taking a very long time. There is no column by which we can divide the dataframe in a segmented fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use [limit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit.html) -

```
pd_df = ....

sparkDF_1k = sparkDF.limit(1000)

pd_df = pd.concat([pd_df,sparkDF_1k.toPandas()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firstThousand = train.limit(1000).collect()[:1000]
df = spark.createDataFrame(firstThousand)
df.toPandas()
```

Comment: Your solutions collects all rows and slice 1000 after it. It must use `.take(1000)` or `limit(1000).collect()`.

Comment: Just curious, doesn't the line ```df = spark.createDataFrame(firstThousand)``` again creates the spark dataframe and we  face the similar issue with toPanas()

Comment: why do you recreate the dataframe ? can't you just `df.limit(1000).toPandas()` ?